# Remove toolbar from Eclipse's package explorer?

Tags: eclipse

After installing Eclipse on Ubuntu, I noticed that every UI element looked ridiculously big compared to Eclipse on Windows. I'm trying to slim it down to make more room for the actual editor. One of the biggest space wasters is the toolbar in the Package Explorer. I didn't see any options inside of Eclipse to hide this. What can I do to get rid of this?

[image: (This is the said toolbar I want to remove)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to stop this displaying.

If you make the view wider it should move up to be in the same line as the 'Package Explorer' text.

Comment: Increasing the tab size + making it wider worked. Still pretty big but much better than before. Thanks.